# @functions vs PageModel in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, razor-pages

Coming from Blazor (Razor COMPONENTS aka .razor files) it does not matter if one uses the `@code` directive or creating a *code behind* `.razor.cs` file, since AFAIK they are both mashed together since they are `partial classes`. This looks somewhat similar, but is fundamentally different from razor pages .cshtml PageModel.

However I have seen many examples where the `Action Methods` aka `OnGet()` `OnPost()` have been written in both places. So my question is:

#### Is there any difference or implications (or official documentation) in declaring members (Properties, Methods) in either the `@functions` block or the `PageModel` ?

Like, what if both have an exact same member (which is theoretically possible, since they are different classes - (not tested)... Precedence... an so on ??

Comment: If your Razor Page has any real logic on it, and is doing more than just displaying values, I recommend you use a separate PageModel in a separate class file.

Answer (score 0):

PageModel classes can be instantiated easily and predictably from code for unit testing purposes. You could instantiate an instance of the generated Razor page class, but as far as I know, there is no formal contract for the algorithm used to generated the class name. There is nothing to stop the framework developers from changing the naming convention from one version of the SDK to another, breaking all your tests.